# Why won't this Laplace transform work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Solving an IVP:

$$y'' - 2y' +5y = 0 $$
$$ y(0) = 2, y'(0) = 4$$

Taking the Laplace transform of both sides 
$$\mathcal{L}{y''} - 2\mathcal{L}{y'} +5\mathcal{L}{y} = 0$$
$$[YS^2 - S(y0) - y'(0)] - 2[SY - (y0)] + [5Y] = 0$$
$$YS^2 - S2 - 4 - 2SY + 4 + 5Y = 0$$
$$Y(S^2 -2S +5) - 2S = 0$$
$$Y = \frac{2S}{(S^2 -2S +5)}$$
$$Y = \frac{2S}{(S-1)^2 +4}$$

Taking the inverse Laplace transform we get $y = 2e^t \cos{2t}$, but the answer is supposed to be $y = 2e^t \cos{2t} + e^t \sin{2t}$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How did you compute the inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: Wait, that is right. I was using the fact that $\mathcal{L}(e^{-at}f(t)) = F(s-a) $, but that isn't right becuse then I would need to extend the numerator to read $(s-1)+1$ and then the extra term would have inverse transform $e^tsin(2t)$ ! Wow, good catch! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've computed the inverse Laplace transform incorrectly:
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{2s}{(s-1)^2 + 4}\right](t) 
= e^t\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{2(u+1)}{u^2 + 4}\right](t) 
= e^t\left(
2\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{u}{u^2 + 4}\right](t) +
2\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{u^2 + 4}\right](t) 
\right) = e^t \left(
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{u/2}{(u/2)^2 + 1}\right](t) +
\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{(u/2)^2 + 1}\right](t) 
\right) = e^t \left(
2\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{w}{w^2 + 1}\right](2t) +
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{w^2 + 1}\right](2t) 
\right) = e^t (2\cos 2t + \sin 2t)
$$

Comment: Thank you! Aah, such a dumb mistake. Thank you so much for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

Your inverse laplace transform is wrong.
Notice that the numerator should also have the $s-1$ term to write the solution you got. 
The correct solution would be:

$Y=$ $ 2s\over{(s-1)^2+4}$

=$2(s-1)\over{(s-1)^2+4}$+$2\over{(s-1)^2+4}$

Now Taking the inverse laplace transform you get the required result